# htaccess file failed to 500 error for wordpress redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am newbie in creating htaccess file, I googled a bit and created .htaccess file 
with 301 redirects it has multiple redirect 
after uploaded it gives me an 500 error.
please guide me, am I doing it wrong.
my site uses WordPress 3.5.1

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/warwickshire-wedding-venues/coventry-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-venue-directory/west-midlands-weddings/coventry-weddings/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/warwickshire-wedding-venues/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire-weddings/banbury-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/west-midlands-weddings/birmingham-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/crystal-glance/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/silk/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/die-cut-leather-201/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/price/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/metallic/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/zen-lay-flat/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /info-about-your-wedding-photographer/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/leather/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/graphistudio-hard-cover-dust-jacket-books/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/neo-classic/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /info-about-your-wedding-photographer/faqs-about-your-wedding-photographer/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /info-about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials-about-your-wedding-photographer/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/graphistudio-premium-books/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/gold-wedding-photography-packages/storybook-gold/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-photo-gallery/reportagephotojournalistic-wedding-photography-portfolio/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/full-day-packages/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/bronze-wedding-photography-packages/graphistudio-bronze/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/silver-wedding-photography-packages/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio/die-cut-leather/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/classic-leather-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-201-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/soft-silk-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /contact-2/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-201-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/metallic-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/crystal-glance-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/classic-leather-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/
redirect 301 /dc-news/test-3/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/book-bound-exd-ex/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/zen-lay-flat-ex-hardcover-book/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /storybooks-albums/asuka-book/zen-lay-flat-book-impact/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/graphistudio-premium-books/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /contact/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/bronze-wedding-photography-packages/asuka-bronze/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/disc-only-wedding-photography-packages/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-photo-gallery/romantic-wedding-photography-portfolio/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/graphistudio-hard-cover-dust-jacket-books/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /home/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /info-about-your-wedding-photographer/dvd-slideshow/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/silver-wedding-photography-packages/storybook-silver/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/   
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/disc-only-wedding-photography-package/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /prices/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northampton-wedding-venues/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/crystal-glance-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about/faq/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /cyprus-weddings/prices/no-frills/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /contact-your-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/bronze-wedding-photography-packages/jorgensen-bronze/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-4/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /faqs-about-your-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /two-column-gallery/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-3/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /dc-news/category/warwickshire/rugby/brownsover-hall-hotel/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/northamptonshire/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-4/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/hellidon-lakes-hotel/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/worcestershire/worcester-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/portfolio_category/natural-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/category/oxfordshire/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/full-wedding-supplier-directory-to-help-you-make-your-decisions/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire/henley-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/daventry/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire/brackley-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/daventry-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/west-midlands-weddings/coventry-weddings/comment-page-1/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/west-midlands-weddings/coventry-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/wedding-photography-christina-owen/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/gloucestershire/cheltenham-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/gloucestershire/gloucester-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/buckinghamshire/aylesbury-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/buckinghamshire/buckingham-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/berkshire/reading-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/bronze-wedding-photography-packages/comment-page-1/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/wedding-photography-clare-david/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/platinum-wedding-photography-packages/storybook-platinum/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire/bicester-wedding/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire/corby-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-6/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-1/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire/wellingborough-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/wellingborough-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/graphistudio-wedding-storybook/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/brackley-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/worcestershire/droitwich-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/berkshire/newbury-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/faqs-about-your-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/extras/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-7/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/warwickshire-wedding-venues/nuneaton-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire/kettering-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/berkshire/hungerford-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/worcestershire/bromsgrove-wedding/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/worcestershire/redditch-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/berkshire/slough-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire/witney-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-7/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-5/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-1/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/package-2/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /dc-news/page/2/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/page/3/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/page/4/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-3/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/wedding-photographer-package-prices/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/rugby/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/category/news/personal/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/oxfordshire-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/category/warwickshire/rugby/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/warwickshire-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/portfolio/natural-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/your-special-moments-captured/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/portfolio/andrea-marius/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /sitemap/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-6/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/help-with-your-web-gallery/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/more-testimonials/even-more-testimonials/more-and-more-testimonials/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/best-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/more-testimonials/even-more-testimonials/more-and-more-happy-brides-and-grooms/feed/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/more-testimonials/even-more-testimonials/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/wedding-photography-package-5/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /natural-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/warwickshire-wedding-venues/rugby-weddings/comment-page-1/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/warwickshire-wedding-venues/rugby-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/more-testimonials/even-more-testimonials/more-and-more-happy-brides-and-grooms/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/more-testimonials/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire-weddings/oxford-weddings/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/bronze-wedding-photography-packages/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /testimonials-about-your-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /privacy-policy/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/brownsover-hall-hotel/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/natural-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/stunning-natural-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/world-class-wedding-photographer/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/frontslider/handcrafted-wedding-storybooks/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/category/northamptonshire/daventry/hellidon-lakes-hotel/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/tag/worcestershire-wedding-photography/www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/test-2/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/west-midlands-weddi http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /http://www.dc-photographic.co.uk/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire-wedding http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-package-prices/] http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /Natural http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /gallery-test/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/test-to-add-tab-content/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /a/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /dc-news/testing/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /Wedding http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /warwick/mi/mi_harb.html http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/oxfordshire-weddings/oxford-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-venue-directory/northamptonshire-wedding-venues/northampton-weddings/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /info-about-your-wedding-photographer/testimonials-about-your-wedding-photographer/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-201-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /graphistudio-wedding-storybook/die-cut-leather-wedding-storybook/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /www.dcphotographic.co.uk/privacy-policy/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /wedding-photographers-photo-gallery/romantic-wedding-photography-portfolio/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
redirect 301 /contact/ http://www.dcphotographic.co.uk/
```

Comment: Add your redirect code before `</IfModule>` also try to one rule first if it works add others.

Comment: @Rikesh Thanks for reply I already tried it ! Does it something to do with my server ?

Answer (score 2):

You .htaccess file works on my server.  It does not give me a 500 error when I use it.  The redirects work fine for me when used on my server.

Look in your server's error_log file if you have access to it.  That file will tell you more information about what the problem actually is caused by.

Try putting just one rule and see if that works.

Then try putting in half the rules.

Then the other half.

Using this technique you can narrow in on which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Thansk for your kind efforts @Stephen I tried it adding rules one by one but it crashed with first rule , So I replaced it with other rule but same thing happens! does it has anything to do with my server ?

Comment: It sounds like it has something to do with your server.  What type of server is it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that Apache doesn't have mod_alias installed, that module enables the "redirect" directive.  You could try using rewrite directives to redirect instead `RewriteRule ^info-about-your-wedding-photographer\/$ / [R=301,L]`